# How to remove DVD DRIVE & free space it occupies?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I probably made this drive to create a virtual environment in VMware. Now I have removed the Ubuntu virtual machine from VMWare & I want to delete this DVD DRIVE E too. How do I do so?

[image: image1]

[The option to delete volume is disabled in Disk Management.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrdQ9.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate if you, mounted the disk, from within Windows.  Difficult to submit an answer, indicating what you should actually do, without that vital information.

Comment: okay, thanks! I will take care from now onwards. For now: problem solved by @harrymc's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an ISO file that you have mounted as a volume,
and which you cannot delete using the Device Manager.

The tool to use is Windows Explorer: Right-click the drive and click *Eject*:

[image]

For more information see
[How to mount or unmount ISO images on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-mount-or-unmount-iso-images-windows-10).